# Get the number of reviews and average rating of a product from amazon

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I am using amazon product api to get the price and the image of a product. I want to get the number of reviews and average rating of that product. How can get the number of reviews and average rating of that product using this api. Or suggest me other ways to get the number of reviews and average rating of that product.
Here is my code:

```html
 <?php

// Region code and Product ASIN
$response = getAmazonPrice("com", "B00IGUUZJM");

function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

 $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
  "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
  "ItemId" => $asin,
  "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
  "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
 ));

 $item = $xml->Items->Item;
 $title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
 $url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
 $image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
 $price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
 $code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
 $qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

 if ($qty !== "0") {
  $response = array(
   "code" => $code,
   "price" => number_format((float) ($price / 100), 2, '.', ''),
   "image" => $image,
   "url" => $url,
   "title" => $title
  );
 }

 return $response;
}

function getPage($url) {

 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $html = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $html;
}

function aws_signed_request($region, $params) {

 $public_key = "";
 $private_key = "";

 $method = "GET";
 $host = "ecs.amazonaws." . $region;
 $host = "webservices.amazon." . $region;
 $uri = "/onca/xml";

 $params["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
 $params["AssociateTag"] = "elitep06-20"; // Put your Affiliate Code here
 $params["AWSAccessKeyId"] = $public_key;
 $params["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
 $params["Version"] = "2011-08-01";

 ksort($params);

 $canonicalized_query = array();
 foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
  $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
  $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
  $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
 }

 $canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

 $string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
 $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
 $signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

 $request = "http://" . $host . $uri . "?" . $canonicalized_query . "&Signature=" . $signature;
 $response = getPage($request);



 $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($movies);

 $pxml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
 if ($pxml === False) {
  return False;// no xml
 } else {
  return $pxml;
 }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 Amazon removed those information the API. The only thing you get is a URL in `reviews` which points to a HTML doc which is supposed to be used in an IFrame. You could scrape this document, but you will hit some ratelimits pretty soon.